# Parameter to check if all values have joined when joining two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I often have two data frames that I wish to join, where I expect all values to join. If not all values are present in both data frames, I want it to return an error.

Here is a MWE:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df1  <- data.frame(
    id  = c(1:5),
    value1 = rep(1, 5)
)

print(df1)
#>   id value1
#> 1  1      1
#> 2  2      1
#> 3  3      1
#> 4  4      1
#> 5  5      1

df2  <- data.frame(
    id  = c(1:4),
    value2 = rep(2, 4)
)

print(df2)
#>   id value2
#> 1  1      2
#> 2  2      2
#> 3  3      2
#> 4  4      2

df3  <- inner_join(
    df1, 
    df2,
    by = "id")

print(df3)
#>   id value1 value2
#> 1  1      1      2
#> 2  2      1      2
#> 3  3      1      2
#> 4  4      1      2

# Check if all values have joined
stopifnot(
    nrow(df3) == max(nrow(df1), nrow(df2))
)
#> Error: nrow(df3) == max(nrow(df1), nrow(df2)) is not TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

This works, but I do not like the `stopifnot()`. It feels cumbersome, and particularly if I wish to overwrite df2, then I need to create a temp value `df2_previous_row_num = nrow(df2)` and then do `stopifnot(nrow(df2) == df2_previous_row_num)`.

Also the `nrow()` test only works if all values in id are unique. There are other methods, e.g. `stopifnot(c(df1$id %in% df3$id, df2$id %in% df3$id))` but again these are ugly.

Really what I am looking for is a parameter that makes the join fail if some values do not join. Something like, `inner_join(df1, df2, fail_if_not_all_present = TRUE)`.

I am not attached to the tidyverse - if there is a base R or data.table way of doing this then I would consider those.

Does anyone know anything?

Comment: I suspect you're going to have a hard time finding a function that does *just that*. For instance, if you want to preserve all keys from one or both of the frames, you need left, right, or full joins, not an inner join. If you want all keys to be present, then there is nothing in the "join calculus" (referencing SQL join as well as R's `merge`) that mandates presence of keys in the output. Since you don't think @RonakShah's answer is right for you, and `stopifnot` feels wrong, then your only remaining option is to `full_join` with canary columns, then look for `NA`s. That's not generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try writing a custom inner join function.

```
custom_inner_join <- function(data1,data2,by, fail_if_not_all_present = FALSE) {
  if(fail_if_not_all_present) {
    vals1 <- do.call(paste, data1[cols])
    vals2 <- do.call(paste, data2[cols])
    if(all(vals1 %in% vals2) && all(vals2 %in% vals1)) {
      merge(data1, data2, by)
    } else stop('Not all key values are present')
  } else {
    merge(data1, data2, by)
  }
}

custom_inner_join(df1, df2, 'id')

#  id value1 value2
#1  1      1      2
#2  2      1      2
#3  3      1      2
#4  4      1      2

custom_inner_join(df1, df2, 'id', fail_if_not_all_present = TRUE)
```

> Error in custom_inner_join(df1, df2, "id", fail_if_not_all_present = TRUE) :
> Not all key values are present

Comment: Thanks - this is OK but it seems like more extra code than using `stopifnot()` to test that they all joined. I was hoping someone might know of existing functionality within current pacakges. I appreciate the response though.